# Define log likelihood for CJS model in Stan

Tags: survival, likelihood, stan

FYI, I'm new to Stan and this is my first question here.

I'm unsure how to calculate the log likelihood for a Cormack-Jolley-Seber model in Stan. Can anyone help me with this?

Background: I've made 4 models all using [this](https://github.com/stan-dev/example-models/blob/master/misc/ecology/mark-recapture/cjs-K.stan) as the foundation. Model 1. - two populations with same phi and p. Model 2. - same phi, but different p, etc. I would like to evaluate models with WAIC via the `loo` package in R, but it requires defining the log likelihood within Stan's "generated quantities" block. [Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/loo/vignettes/loo2-with-rstan.html) is an example of this being done for a logistic regression model. Let me know if I can provide further clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also posted this question to a different forum and received an answer. In case it's helpful to anyone in the future, the answer can be found here https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/cjs-log-likelihood/15112